# "subscript out of bounds" error in str_extract_all

Tags: r, stringr, tm, quanteda

I am trying extract date information from multiple text files using str_extract_all. If I do a single file, it works fine. But, when I put it in for loop, it gives me this error.

I have already tried 'anytime' and it doesn't work, and none of the other basic time extraction tools do not work.

Here is the part of the code that is giving me trouble:

```
file.names <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/jwils/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/CNN_files/AC360",  pattern = "txt$")

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){

named <- read.table(file.names[i], header=FALSE, sep="", fill = TRUE)

renamed <- corpus(file.names[i])

date <- str_extract_all(texts(renamed)
                        , "(\\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Dec(?:ember)?) (?:19[7-9]\\d|2\\d{3})(?=\\D|$))|(\\b(?:JAN(?:UARY)?|FEB(?:RUARY)?|MAR(?:CH)?|APR(?:IL)?|MAY|JUN(?:E)?|JUL(?:Y)?|AUG(?:UST)?|SEP(?:TEMBER)?|NOV(?:EMBER)?|OCT(?:OBER)?|DEC(?:EMBER)?) (?:19[7-9]\\d|2\\d{3})(?=\\D|$))|((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4})|(\\b(JAN(UARY)?|FEB(RUARY)?|MAR(CH)?|APR(IL)?|MAY|JUN(E)?|JUL(Y)?|AUG(UST)?|SEP(TEMBER)?|OCT(OBER)?|NOV(EMBER)?|DEC(EMBER)?)\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4})"
                        , simplify = TRUE)[,1]
}
```

I expect this code to pull out the date from a series of text files that look like,

"Date
Aired on December 12, 2018 at
Text
a bunch of text from a transcript"

What I get is the error message, "subscript out of bounds." I do not know what this means. As I said, it works on a single file, but not in the loop. Thanks for any and all assistance.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve from the line `renamed <- corpus(file.names[i])`. Are you making a corpus object of filename?

Comment: Yes. The str_extract_all does not work without it. I tried to make the corpus from the variable, named. But, I received more errors. This seemed to be the simple fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with you not getting the result you are expecting via the `[, 1]` index operation.  If one of the files does not contain a match, then with the loop it will return an empty scalar that cannot be indexed that way.

Here's a simpler way: use **readtext** to input the files.

```
library("quanteda")
library("stringr")

corp <- readtext::readtext("C:/Users/jwils/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/CNN_files/AC360/*.txt") %>%
    corpus()

docvars(corp, "date") <- 
    str_extract_all(texts(corp),
                    "(\\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Dec(?:ember)?) (?:19[7-9]\\d|2\\d{3})(?=\\D|$))|(\\b(?:JAN(?:UARY)?|FEB(?:RUARY)?|MAR(?:CH)?|APR(?:IL)?|MAY|JUN(?:E)?|JUL(?:Y)?|AUG(?:UST)?|SEP(?:TEMBER)?|NOV(?:EMBER)?|OCT(?:OBER)?|DEC(?:EMBER)?) (?:19[7-9]\\d|2\\d{3})(?=\\D|$))|((Jan(uary)?|Feb(ruary)?|Mar(ch)?|Apr(il)?|May|Jun(e)?|Jul(y)?|Aug(ust)?|Sep(tember)?|Oct(ober)?|Nov(ember)?|Dec(ember)?)\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4})|(\\b(JAN(UARY)?|FEB(RUARY)?|MAR(CH)?|APR(IL)?|MAY|JUN(E)?|JUL(Y)?|AUG(UST)?|SEP(TEMBER)?|OCT(OBER)?|NOV(EMBER)?|DEC(EMBER)?)\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{4})"
                    simplify = TRUE)[, 1]

# to verify
summary(corp)
```

This assigns the dates to your corpus as a new document variable.  You could also assigned them just to a vector (e.g. `date`) if you prefer.

I don't have any of your original files and therefore cannot guarantee that this will work, but I as long as you have the dates in your text files and the `readtext()` call finds them, it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My goal is to extract the date from each file in a series of 4469 files, and do it one at a time (hence the for loop). I am trying to rename each file as the date extracted from that particular file. So, CNNtrump.txt becomes 2019-06-21.txt. Each text file has the format: "Date Aired on December 12, 2018 (for example) Text a bunch of text from a transcript." This set of dates goes from 2009 to 2019. I want to extract each date and assign that vector as the new name of the file as it prints it to a new directory. Does that make sense?